# Экспорт файлов scss

Tags: angular

Есть файл стилей `app.component.scss`, в котором описаны глабальные стили. Как мне наследовать стили из этого файла в файлы стилей в папке `component`, например в `index.component/index/index.component.scss`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: импортировать этот файл?

Comment: @overthesanity  не весь файл, некоторые стили, таккме как шрифты, `li` , `ul` и тд. Не писать же мне их в каждом файле заново.

Comment: так а зачем вам `app.componnet.scss`? в папке scss создавайте отдельные файлы и импортируйте их по нужде, например `_fonts.scss`, `_lists.scss`